# php rename function is not working

Tags: php, codeigniter, rename

I have written the following Codeigniter function to rename a folder but its not working, the folder also contains 2 sub-folders and that folders contains some CSS and image files.

```
    function _rename_theme_folder($old_name, $new_name){
      echo THEMES_BASE_URL . $old_name."<br>";
      echo THEMES_BASE_URL . $new_name;
      rename(THEMES_BASE_URL . $old_name, THEMES_BASE_URL . $new_name);
      exit;
    }
```

**Note:** I can read and write files to the same directory but renaming is not working.

***Output of the above function:***

```
D:\wwwroot\ds_menu\static\front\naveed
D:\wwwroot\ds_menu\static\front\naveedkhan
```

Comment: Is `rename` returning `false` then?

Comment: rename is returning nothing. I tried printing its return value.

Comment: `var_dump` the return value. Also, please check that `strlen` for each matches what it's displaying.

Comment: @Abolarinstephen Why would they try this? They're blatantly on Windows.

Comment: @JonStirling var dump returns `boolean false` but `strlen` returns the correct length of each string.

Comment: @Muhammad Okay. Does a file already exist in the directory with that name?

Comment: the directory which I want to rename contains 2 folders and that folders also contains some css and image files. but there is no file with the same name as parent directory.

Comment: So `D:\wwwroot\ds_menu\static\front\naveedkhan` doesn't exist?

Comment: yes because its a new name.

Comment: Okay, the next thing to check is that the php user actually has write access to both the folder you're trying to move, and the folder that it's contained in. If it's not permissions, I'm not sure what's left.

Comment: @JonStirling I think the problem is there with the write access of sub folder, now when I removed the sub folders the renaming worked.

Comment: @JonStirling Thank you so much for your help. :-)